# Unable to change password - user account not in account settings list

Tags: 16.04, password, users

I am trying to change my password but there is no account in the User Account Settings list and I can not unlock the password field.

[image]

Comment: Why lubuntu tag?

Comment: Click on the lock button it asks your password, enter your pass then you can edit.

Comment: @Ravexina Unfortunately not. The "Lock" button will lock the settings again after having been unlocked by the "unlock" button. The problem I see here is that there actually isn't any user account in the list at all.

Comment: Can you please open a terminal, run the commands `id` and `getent passwd $(whoami)` and [edit] your question to show us the output?

Comment: @ByteCommander I don't have much GUI applications, so it was a guess... good you clarify that it's a wrong guess ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the password in the terminal.

Open a terminal window and type:

```
sudo passwd USERNAME
```

where USERNAME is the name of the user account you want to change the password for, or (even simpler) just type

```
passwd
```

to change the password of the account you're running the command from.

When prompted, then type your current password, then the new password, and finally retype the new password.

Comment: Thanks for solution. Is there any way to enable user account editable

Comment: You should not use `sudo passwd USERNAME` unless necessary (when you forgot the password), because that way you will force-change the password. This could get you into slight trouble if there is anything else in that user's account depending on the password. A famous example is if you use home folder encryption. Always prefer the more simple `passwd` to change the password of the logged in account wherever possible.